# Entity Framework Core 6, Contains Optimization and Pagination

Tags: sql, linq, pagination, entity-framework-core

I have made a LINQ query to a database using entity framework.

Currently I have a database of about 10000 entries. When performing a search, it takes about 15-20 seconds before i receive a response.

Here is my query code:

```
        private async Task<StationSearchResult> SimpleSearch(SearchQuery filter, Guid currentUserId, bool showInformationAsPublic) {
            var query = _context.Station
                .Include(x => x.Workers)
                .Include(x => x.WorkerLeads)
                .Include(x => x.StationCustomFields)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.CustomFieldResponsible)
                .Include(x => x.StationType)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.StationTypeResponsible)
                .Where(x => x.Title.Contains(filter.SearchText) 
                            || x.Description.Contains(filter.SearchText) 
                            || x.Alias.Contains(filter.SearchText) 
                            || x.StationCustomFields.FirstOrDefault(t => t.StringValue.Contains(filter.SearchText)).StringValue.Contains(filter.SearchText));


            if (!showInformationAsPublic)
            {
                query = query.Where(x => 
                    x.IsPublic == true 
                    || x.Workers.Any(t => t.ad_id == currentUserId) 
                    || x.WorkerLeads.Any(t => t.ad_id == currentUserId));
            }

            var result = await query.OrderBy(GetOrderByProperty(filter.OrderBy)).ToListAsync();

            return new StationSearchResult
            {
                Total = result.Count,
                Workplaces = result.Skip(filter.Skip).Take(filter.Count == 0 ? 10 : filter.Count).ToList()
            };
        }
```

If i remove my includes, the query time is drastically reduced ~1s, but I need to include data from the station relations.

Is there any way this can be optimized using linq? Or will I have to do a RAW sql query to send to the database?

It is also a requirement, that my searchText matches a value from Title, Alias or The string value from the station custom fields, which can be any given value depending on the station.

Comment: Use `AsSplitQuery()` or remove not needed Includes.

Comment: Include the `Skip` and `Take` before doing the `ToListAsync`.

Comment: @NetMage If I do this, the total will always say 10, assuming there are more than 10.
In that case, the frontend which displays the data, wont know how many pages it should display.

Comment: Or if you can, consider [keyset pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/pagination#keyset-pagination).

Comment: Then I would run a separate query ending in `Count` to get the total count, which should be more efficient. The time difference between the `result` query and the `Count` query could give you an idea of where the delay occurs. Also, do you really need to update the total every page?

Comment: 1. You forgot .AsNoTracking() ...unless you really intend to modify the returned search items. 2. maybe you should have a materialized sql-view? it will cost you storage and insert-performance though...